# Download Excel file from GWT client

Tags: servlets, gwt, apache-poi

I need to generate on my GWT application an xls file (generated on server side with apache-poi) from client.
I want that when the user click on a button, appears a file chooser the allow him to save the generated file.

To begin I've created my servlet:

```
public class DownloadServlet extends HttpServlet
{

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        // What I have to insert here?!
    }

    public void getXlsFile()
    {
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Datatypes in Java");
        Object[][] datatypes = { { "Datatype", "Type", "Size(in bytes)" }, { "int", "Primitive", 2 }, { "float", "Primitive", 4 }, { "double", "Primitive", 8 }, { "char", "Primitive", 1 }, { "String", "Non-Primitive", "No fixed size" } };

        int rowNum = 0;

        for (Object[] datatype : datatypes) {
            Row row = sheet.createRow(rowNum++);
            int colNum = 0;
            for (Object field : datatype) {
                Cell cell = row.createCell(colNum++);
                if( field instanceof String ) {
                    cell.setCellValue((String) field);
                }
                else if( field instanceof Integer ) {
                    cell.setCellValue((Integer) field);
                }
            }
        }

        try {
            FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("MyFirstExcel.xlsx");
            workbook.write(outputStream);
            workbook.close();
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Now the questions are:

- How do I have to fill doGet method?
- And how I can call this servlet from client side?

Note that client side I don't know the xls file path because I want to create the xls file "on the fly" on server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have created a servlet and have your xls file ready. All you have to do is to push the data into `HttpServletResponse` object.

First, you don't need to save the file. Change the `getXlsFile()` method to return `XSSFWorkbook` and remove the `try / catch` block at the end.

Now, `doGet` method:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    HSSFWorkbook workbook = getXlsFile();
    String fileName = "MyFirstExcel.xlsx";

    resp.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
    resp.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"");
    resp.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
    resp.getOutputStream().write(workbook.getBytes());
    resp.getOutputStream().close();
    resp.flushBuffer();

    workbook.close();
}
```

How to call the server?

You need to add a *servlet mapping* in `web.xml` file:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>myServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>fully.qualified.className</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>myServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/path/to/the/servlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

In short: servlet mapping *maps* the url to the servlet class. So, when you open `/path/to/the/servlet` the `fully.qualified.className` servlet is called.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. But how can I call this from client side to invoke browser chooser file? I think that I need someting like this: String url = GWT.getModuleBaseURL() + "downloadService?fileInfo1=" + fileInfo1;
Window.open( url, "_blank", "status=0,toolbar=0,menubar=0,location=0");

Comment: Yes, try that. And you can omit the `GWT.getModuleBaseURL()` part of the url - it is not needed when calling from the page loaded from the same host. You can also try to change `Window.open....` to `Window.Location.assign(url);`.

Comment: Good! It works!! Just last question...The browser doesn't show to me file chooser for file saving but It starts automatically with the download. How Can I invoke file chooser?

Comment: Check in your browser. In Chrome, for example, set *Ask where to save each file before downloading.* in *Downloads* section. I'm glad I could help :)

Comment: Thanks for your support!